# git pull is not changing the files in GodDaddy server

Tags: git, github

I have setup git in my GoDaddy server, git clone is working correctly, but when I'm doing a pull action, it says 1 file changed which is correct but it doesn't change the files, It gives me the output below, can anyone please help me on how to resolve this issue?

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From https://github.com/nikultaka/wordpress_plugins
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating b3452b6..eb9e71d
Fast-forward
 mi/website-custom-plugin/website-custom-plugin.php | 4 ++--
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Is your cloned directory same as the hosted directory?

Comment: @MohamedAneesA Yes it is same

Comment: Just open the website-custom-plugin.php and see if your file changes is there. If there is any js changes, you will need to hard-reload your browser to see the changes

Comment: I already checked that file it doesn't affecting the code

Comment: Are you sure you are pulling from the right branch?